# Making meet the team page

Tags: html

I am manufacturing a "meet the team" page, i want to display my team mates in table format without borders. However, there is always a grey border showing out.....
how can I make a table completely without border?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/2/26/Andrew.PNG" width="200" height="200"></td>
    <td><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/2/26/Andrew.PNG" width="200" height="200"></td>
    <td><img src="http://2017.igem.org/wiki/images/2/26/Andrew.PNG" width="200" height="200"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: works fine in my browser

Comment: Must be due to the browser defaulting CSS. Can't you just set the border to 0?

Comment: works fine in chrome , firefox and i tried  running it on w3school and it runs fine.

Comment: @Carcigenicate would you mind to show me how to do this in css? I just know set table border to be 0 in html

Comment: @AlanChiu You already tried setting the border to 0?arenyoynsure the border is on the table itself? Did you try 0ing out the border of the rows and elements as well?

Comment: Works fine in Safari. What browser are you seeing the borders in?